# jQuery selectors don't work in Fotorama.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fotorama

What am I doing wrong here?

[**Link to codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/PqqrNd?editors=101)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('img');
  console.log(img.length); //returns 0 WHY?
});
```

It returns 0 objects whilst there are 2 `img` tags. I tried to intialize it in many ways, with JS only, with API access. Nothing works. Why jQuery/JavaScript selectors do not work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fotorama` library manipulates your `img` tags, which is the reason why you get `0` at DOM ready. A little hack would be to use timeout.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var img = $('img');
    console.log($('img').length);
},200)
```

*Note: The timeout value cannot be predicted and the plugin might take time to init.

**[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPPjrj)**

Comment: Nice hack. Looks like it works and it returns 2 objects with timeout of ~800.  Anyways, it doesn't allow to change the ``data-fit`` attribute of a particular image. I mean, attribute is applied, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I didn't get you. Are you adding the attribute or the plugin is?

Comment: Fotorama has some API, one of them is ``data-fit``, http://fotorama.io/customize/fit/, it also allows for different images to have different values of this attribute. It applies on an image in the DOM, but it doesn't do anything because it looks like it has to be applied before Fotorama initialization to actually work. E.g. http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/oXXrzG (the grey 400x400 image is supposed to be real 400x400, not zoomed)

Comment: Ahh, got it. Saw their plugin page. Not sure why it isnt working. Try using `contain` or 'none' instead of `cover` to get the original.